# Python requests error

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I am not able to get my head around this error. The same is working in another module. Below is the code.

```
  def _apiQuery(self):
    params = {
              'address': self.address
              }
    try:
      r = requests.get(self.url, params)
      response = r.json()
      return response
    except Exception as e:
      raise
```

Error:

```
    r = requests.get(self.url, params)
TypeError: get() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

However if I do  `r = requests.get(self.url, params=params) this works.`

Comment: Looks like `params` was added between requests [v2.6.2](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v2.6.2/api/#requests.get) and [v2.7.0](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v2.7.0/api/#requests.get). What version are you using?

Comment: it works in another module with exactly same query and works here with `params=params` so definitely not a version issue.

Comment: That would make `params` part of `**kwargs`, which is consistent with the pre-2.7.0 version API. Couldn't say why the other construction works elsewhere. Are they using different python versions or virtual envs where you might have different requests installations?

Comment: And to check that see what `requests.__file__` shows for each of those... that should lead you in the right place if they differ...

Comment: requests : version is 2.13.0 and python version is 2.7.5

Answer (score 0):

I am using `sublime-text` as IDE in Linux environment. The difference was caused by from where do I start my sublime text.

If I start it just after login. During runtime requests shows version 2.6
If I activate my virtual environment and start it, requests shows version 2.13

So the libs it is using are depending on from where I started the IDE.

as mentioned by @glibdud `params was added between requests v2.6.2 and v2.7.0` hence the issue.